# software scenario sequence editor

Tags: uml, scenarios

The project scenario:

Management, engineers, scientists and users contributes their requirements for a piece of software. They contribute gifs, jpegs, pngs, ms presentation files. They specify the sequence of occurrence.

I want to provide them with a piece of software like the movie scenario and scripting editor. (A movie scenario and scripting editor is a computer aided script writer and scenario presenter in movie production). In my case, I am not producing a movie but documenting and integrating various specifications of software UI sequences.

I need the software to sequence out the UI scenario. A scenario would be comprised by various scenes in specified sequence. A scene is a particular moment of the UI or software state.

I need the software to associate each scene to one or more files (gif/jpg/png/presentation). So that when we present it to mgmt, users, customers, we could progress through the scenario with each scene illustrated by those files.

I need the software to be able to compose sub-scenarios as a standalone project. So that each user could compose his/her own contribution to the project. Then the software should be able to specify project dependency to integrate the scenarios into one big kahuna.

Ideally, the software would generate UML sequences and empty classes.

I think, the gaming software industry might be using something of this nature.

Could anyone please suggest and discuss various software available for the purpose I have described?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't know about any software that does what you describe - but it sounds interesting as an idea - especially with use case modeling...

If I would try to write such a tool, I would probably look at Xtext to create a DSL with editor for those scenario scripts you describe and add some code generation using the Abstract User Interface metamodel from topcased.org (curiously currently down...) modeled after [UsiXML](http://www.usixml.eu/).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I will not be able to discuss, but I could suggest something that I think is similar. [Mindomo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindomo)?

Comment: No mind-mapping is not what I am looking for. More like a movie producer's/director's/scriptwriter's scenario sequence illustrator is what I need, but for software scenarios. Ideally with UML.